# Python BeautifulSoup 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This might seem simple, however i couldn't get this to work. Just started to learn scraping recently and have encountered this problem. Tried the code in python REPL and it seems to be working, however not sure why when i coded it, it wouldn't work.

This is my code below btw. So what i'm trying to do is to extract out the article title, link and picture for my program and this is what i have below.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

beauty_result=[]

def scrape_b2():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://www.instyle.com/beauty'), 'lxml')
    url = 'https://www.instyle.com'
    for article in soup.find_all('article',class_='component tile media image-top type-article'):
        for img in article.find_all('div',class_='component lazy-image thumbnail'):
            for a in article.find('h3'):
                beauty_result.append(json.dumps({
                    'title':a.get_text(strip=True),
                    'link':url+article.find('a')['href'],
                    'image':img.get('data-src')
                }))
    print(beauty_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_b2()
```

And this is the whole traceback of the error that I got:

```
D:\Coding\Python\webscrape env>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 37, in <module> scrape_b2()
File "app.py", line 28, in scrape_b2 'title':a.get_text(strip=True),
File "D:\Coding\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\webscraper_practice\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 742, in getattr self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

This is what i solved it with:

```
def scrape_b2():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://www.instyle.com/beauty'), 'lxml')
    url = 'https://www.instyle.com'
    for article in soup.find_all('article',class_='component tile media image-top type-article'):
        for img in article.find_all('div',class_='component lazy-image thumbnail'):
            h3 = article.find('h3')
            a_link = h3.find('a')
            beauty_result.append(json.dumps({
                'title': a_link.get_text(strip=True),
                'link': url + a_link.get('href'),
                'image': img.get('data-src')
                }))
    print(beauty_result)
```

Comment: Could you write the whole traceback of the error

Comment: looks like the page is loaded dynamically, so the first part of your loop `soup.find_all('article',class_='component tile media image-top type-article')` returns an empty list. You will need to use Selenium, or another means to get that dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you cannot use the `get_text()` method, which is specific to Bs4 object.

What you can do is:

```
h3 = article.find('h3')
a_link = h3.find('a')
beauty_result.append(json.dumps({
    'title': a_link.get_text(strip=True),
    'link': url + a_link.get('href'),
    'image': img.get('data-src')
     }))
```

The previous code replace the loop `for a in article.find('h3'):`

Comment: thanks! This works, but i seem to be getting these symbols in some of the titles `{"title": "The Truth About Those Trendy Hair Vitamins, According to A\\u00a0Hair Specialist"}, {"title": "Jennifer Lopez\\u2019s Curly Lob Makes Gym Hair Look Good"}, {"title": "Everything You Need to Know About HIIPA: The Exercise Trend for People Who Don\\u2019t Have Time to Work Out"}`. Is there any way to remove those as well?

Comment: sorry, how do i encode the string? just started learning to code awhile back, so i'm not too familiar with this yet.

Comment: it seems to be an encoding issue. Search method like `encode('utf-8')`, to decode the `\u2019` and other-like chars

Comment: i found out that it turns out to be json problem, as it converts it into unicode when i save it into my database, but when i display it, it turns back to normal again

Answer (score 0):

The following script will give you the different article titles and their concerning links from that site. It looks like the specific content of that page are generated dynamically but in reality they are not. They are present in the page source with different class names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL = "https://www.instyle.com/beauty"

def get_article_info(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for article in soup.select('.media-body h3.headline a[href^="/"]'):
        title = article.get_text().strip()
        link = urljoin(link,article.get("href").strip())
        yield {"title":title,"url":link}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_article_info(URL):
        print(item['title'],item['url'])
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! This works as well, however @Maaz code fits mine better as i will be saving this json dump into my database later on.